# How to change the functionality of back button to display a list?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

In my app I use `UINavigationController` to navigate through hierarchy of views but I encountered a problem - I need to display a list of buttons (when pushed they go to a view controller) instead of the back button.

What is that functionality called? I know how to change the button title and functionality but don't know how to create this list (a good example of my question is the Facebook left bar which shows Friends and other stuff).

Answer (score 1):

In general you're looking for a *drawer*. That's what it is usually called. There are many libraries/frameworks out there that implement it in a different way so there is no general approach how to "change back button to...".

Check for yourself:

- [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck)
- [DDMenuController](https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController)
- [PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController)
- [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)

Though, [here](http://uxmag.com/articles/adapting-ui-to-ios-7-the-side-menu) you will find a very good article about very unique way how to implement this "hamburger" icon feature. They provide nice research and you'll find some very interesting information there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need control like [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) for showing side menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make modal segue or hide back button programmatically. Then you add your own button and configure it. Default back button only return you to previous view, you need to make your own.